# Error command not found in case bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I write the bash script with the case, and when I run it as follow `./myscript.sh us-west-1d` It causes the error

```
./myscript.sh: line 26:  : command not found
./myscript.sh: line 27:  : command not found
./myscript.sh: line 28:  : command not found
ami-fce3c696 us-east-1
```

But, when I run `./myscript.sh us-west-1b`, it runs normally

Can anyone please show me how to fix this problem?

```
#! /bin/bash
AZ=$1
case $AZ in
      us-east-1b)
              SUBNET="subnet-2a3b5d47"
              SECURITY_GROUP=sg-f7d52998
              INVENTORY_GROUP=collector-use1
              WEIGHT=100
              AMI=ami-fce3c696
              REGION=us-east-1
              ;;
      us-east-1d)
              SUBNET="subnet-e6385e8b"
              SECURITY_GROUP=sg-f7d52998
              INVENTORY_GROUP=collector-use1
              WEIGHT=100
              AMI=ami-fce3c696
              REGION=us-east-1
              ;;
      us-east-1e)
              SUBNET="subnet-07395f6a"
              SECURITY_GROUP=sg-f7d52998
              INVENTORY_GROUP=collector-use1
              WEIGHT=100
              AMI=ami-fce3c696
              REGION=us-east-1
              ;;
esac
echo $SUBNET $SECURITY_GROUP $INVENTORY_GROUP $AMI $REGION
```

Comment: You misspelled `esac`.

Comment: Oh, that's my typo. But, the error is still the same

Comment: I suspect this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/31885409/1126841: Why would a correct shell script give a wrapped/truncated/corrupted error message?.

Comment: I believe my question and his question are not related to each other

Comment: Did you copy this from a windows box into your Linux network and then run it?

Comment: Have you checked if your script has DOS line endings? *That*'s what the other question is about.

Comment: try running dos2unix on your file.

Comment: I created the script and ran it on Mac machine

Comment: what are the line endings of that file? `od -c script.sh`

Comment: run ` cat -v myscript.sh` and see if you have any ^M

Comment: The code you posted is fine. Please check for DOS line endings, because it's the only thing that could explain how the posted code produces an error similar to what you are reporting

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Note that your example parameters do not have matching case branches, so I would expect the output to be an empty line.

Comment: when I run `cat -v myscript.sh`, it doesn't have any ^M

Comment: and, how can I check for DOS line endings ?

Comment: @glennjackman, can you be more specific?

Comment: By using the `od` command I gave you: Do you see `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`

Comment: my last line ending like this `0003040    t   -   2  \n  \t  \t   ;   ;  \n   e   s   a   c  \n`

Comment: Just to eliminate the super-obvious, .... you didn't run the cmd with a `:` for an argument did you? Good luck.

Comment: Actually, I fixed it by replacing `space` with `tab` for all line in my case. Then, it turned out working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the `space` with `tab` for all the line in my case, and it turned out working perfectly fine. Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: Tabs are equivalent to spaces in every shell I am familiar with. The problem must have been somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe they were non-breaking spaces or some other unicode whitespace. @Alexander, what editor do you use?

Comment: @glennjackman you are right. Some other codes with the whitespace, and a few with `tab`. So, I replaced everything with `tab` and it turned out working fine for me

Comment: @glennjackman, I used vim editor, which is already available on MAC

Comment: If you still have the original script (with the error), or can recreate it, have a look at it with `od -cx` or a hex editor to see whether it contains some odd characters. BTW, when you are posting this type of question, where a line number is mentioned, you should also indicate, where line 26 etc. are in your script.

Comment: @user1934428 it is in the case 1d, I am pretty much sure about it. Moreover, it is a piece of code that I wrote, so that's why it appear as line 26.

Comment: I had the same problem where my script was ending with `unknown command: sac` (which was `esac` but it kept eating the first character), and replacing each 4-spaces group with a `\t` fixed the error. No other changes were done to fix it, so looks like mixing whitespaces and tabs actually **is** the cause of the error.