# String concatenating error in shell script executing

Tags: java, shell, awk, sed, grep

This is a wired problem confusing me for days.I want to get a class's full class name from parse the java code file in shell.We can get package name from like:

package com.android.mail.ui;

and get class name from code file path,use shell command 'basename'.
below is my shell scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
get_package_name(){
   java_file=$1
    if [ ! -f $file_path ]; then 
        echo "Sorry,the java file is not exist:$1,please check"
        exit 1
    fi      
    class_base_name=`basename "$java_file" .java`
    echo "class_base_name:$class_base_name"
    package_name=`grep $java_file -e "^package" | awk -F " " '{print $2}' | tr ';' ' ' | sed 's/ //g'`
    echo "package_name get result:$?"
    echo "package_name:$package_name"
```

## method 1,use variable concat directly

```
    classpath_name=$package_name.$class_base_name
    echo "method 1 classpath_name:$classpath_name"
```

## method 2,use sed replace to get concat indirectly

```
    classpath_name2=`echo "aa.bb" | sed "s/aa/$package_name/" | sed "s/bb/$class_base_name/"`
    echo "method 2 classpath_name2:$classpath_name2"
```

}

> The problem is:for some code file the result is ok,like:
>   "class_base_name:MailTransport package_name get result:0
>   package_name:com.android.email.mail.transport method 1
>   classpath_name:com.android.email.mail.transport.MailTransport method 2
>   classpath_name2:com.android.email.mail.transport.MailTransport"
>
> for others it's output is : "class_base_name:EmailApplication
>   package_name get result:0 package_name:com.android.email
>   .EmailApplicationh_name:com.android.email
>   .EmailApplicationh_name2:com.android.email"
>
> the result is totally messing and wrong.I doubt it relates the code
>   content,that really make sense for the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because some of your files use Windows style CRLF (`\r\n`) line terminators.

Here's an example where it works, a normal Unix style LF (`\n`) terminated file:

```
$ file WorkingFile.java
WorkingFile.java: ASCII text

$ cat -v WorkingFile.java
package foo.bar.baz;

$ get_package_name WorkingFile.java
class_base_name:WorkingFile
package_name get result:0
package_name:foo.bar.baz
method 1 classpath_name:foo.bar.baz.WorkingFile
```

Here's an example where it fails, with CRLF line terminators:

```
$ file FailingFile.java
FailingFile.java: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

$ cat -v FailingFile.java
package foo.bar.baz;^M        <--- note hidden control char revealed by -v

$ get_package_name FailingFile.java
class_base_name:FailingFile
package_name get result:0
package_name:foo.bar.baz
.FailingFilesspath_name:foo.bar.baz
```

To fix it, you can delete the extra carriage returns using `tr -d '\r'`. I switched from legacy backticks to modern `$()` to avoid problems with backslashes:

```
package_name=$(grep $java_file -e "^package" | awk -F " " '{print $2}' | tr ';' ' ' | sed 's/ //g' | tr -d '\r')
```

For more information, see [this relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885409/why-would-a-correct-shell-script-give-a-wrapped-truncated-corrupted-error-messag).

Comment: You ROCKKCOR!  I hope I can plus 100 fro you,that saves me!