# If statement inside a for loop

Tags: bash, list, if-statement, for-loop

Here i have a list (/test/list) contains 3 words: foo, bar, bla .
I tried run this code :

```
#!/bin/bash
list=$(cat /test/list)
for i in $list ;do
if [ "$i" = "foo" ]; then
echo "yes $i"
else 
echo "no $i"
fi
done
```

But the output is:

```
no foo
no bar
no bla
```

How can i do for have:

```
yes foo
no bar
no bla
```

I have tried many things but nothing work. Thx for help.

Comment: I've just run your code on a test file and it works... it outputs as you are expecting.

Comment: This is the wrong way to iterate over the contents of a file. See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: It is also possible that `/test/list` contains DOS line endings, in which case the first value is `foo\r`, not `foo`, which would cause the comparison to fail. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31885409/1126841

Comment: @chepner yeah it was a DOS line endings ...thx