# Comparing two numeric variables in Linux

Tags: bash, shell

I have declared two numeric variables but am unable to compare them

```
  remote_file_size=$(curl -sI $URL | grep -i content-length | awk '{print $2}')
  local_file_size=$(ls -l $file_location | awk '{print $5}')

  if [ "$local_file_size" -eq "$remote_file_size" ]; then
      echo "Database up to date. Update not required"
  else
      echo "Database needs to be updated! Downloading newer version"
      wget --continue -O $file_location $URL
  fi
```

I've also tried,

```
 if [[ "$local_file_size"="$remote_file_size" ]];
 if [[ "$local_file_size"=="$remote_file_size" ]];
 if [[ $local_file_size==$remote_file_size ]];
 if [[ $local_file_size == $remote_file_size ]];
```

Comment: Btw.: bash can only deal with [integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer).

Comment: Btw.: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/74329)

Comment: have you done `echo $local_file_size .... $remote_file_size` to confirm that both values are integers? Good luck.

Comment: @Cyrus That was very helpful. I found that using `stat -c %s -- $file_location` to obtain file size was much better option than using `ls`

Comment: yes @shellter I have echoed after every step to see if they are getting declared properly and if they are integers. Since I am using file size, can there be problems of number being out of range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl` is notorious for outputting invisible but harmful carriage returns directly from HTTP responses. This is why you're getting this [weird, wrapped message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885409/why-would-a-correct-shell-script-give-a-wrapped-truncated-corrupted-error-messag):

```
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

You can strip them with `tr`:

```
#                                  v-- Here
remote_file_size=$(curl -sI $URL | tr -d '\r' | grep -i content-length | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: That works! Stripping `curl` of carriage returns now works. Probably curl was giving the problems in the first place.

Comment: @Ayushya Yay! This is easily diagnosed from the error message, so make sure to include that in future questions

Comment: Funny thing is, there were no errors when I was not using typeset. Since `if` evaluated the condition whatsoever the variables were, whether integers or not.

Answer (score 1):

You may find typesetting the variables as integers to be helpful:

```
$ typeset -i a="123"
$ typeset -i b="242"
$ [ $a -lt $b ] && echo 'a < b' || echo 'a >= b'
a < b
$ a=545
$ [ $a -lt $b ] && echo 'a < b' || echo 'a >= b'
a >= b
```

Comment: typesetting is giving error: tried `typeset -i local_file_size="$(ls -l $file_location | awk '{print $5}')"` and `typeset -i local_file_size=$(ls -l $file_location | awk '{print $5}')`. With and without quotes, both giving error.

Comment: The error was given by `typeset -i remote_file_size=$(curl -sI $URL | grep -i content-length | awk '{print $2}')`. Other one works fine. Error goes as:
`")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "`

Comment: The integer attribute isn't really that useful. It doesn't affect comparisons, since you need to use the correct set of operators anyway. Aside from its use as documentation, the only effect it has is to treat the value as an arithmetic expression when you *assign* to the variable.

Comment: I don't see how `typeset` will solve OP's problem. It's not required (in bash, anyway) in order to use `-eq`, etc. The only thing it buys you is it will spit out an error if you try to do something like `a=2.5`. And it doesn't seem to complain at all if you do `a="foobar"`. Instead it just quietly sets `a` to `0`. In any case, OP's failure to use `-eq` is neither caused by not using `typeset -i`, nor will it be fixed by using it. Except that it *might* point out to him where he's assigning a non-integer value.

Comment: Thanks @bishop It did point out that the problem was related to carriage returns in `curl`.