# Docker: Windows and Linux different output. Why?

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, carriage-return

I discovered a really strange behaviour of my Dockerfile. It works perfectly under my linux machine but under windows I got a weird output running my container. Could somebody check my commands and tell me what is wrong with them? Why it works under ubuntu without any problems? I thought docker ensures that it can be started in the same way under different operations systems...

Windows commands:

`git clone https://github.com/falent/googleHomeAssistantExpressNodeJS.git C:\Users\%username%\Documents\googleHomeAssistantExpressNodeJS`

`$ cd C:\Users\%username%\Documents\googleHomeAssistantExpressNodeJS`

`$ sudo build -t assistant .`

`$ docker run -v /C/Users/%username%/Documents/googleHomeAssistantExpressNodeJS:/skill -it --name myAssistant assistant`

I got this output under windows:

```
: not foundypoint.sh: 2: /skill/entrypoint.sh:
sleep: invalid time interval '10s\r'
Try 'sleep --help' for more information.
/skill/entrypoint.sh: 4: cd: can't cd to /skill
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:slim

RUN npm install -g nodemon@1.14.7

COPY package.json /skill/package.json

RUN mkdir -p /skill/
WORKDIR /skill/
RUN npm install

COPY entrypoint.sh /skill
RUN chmod +x /skill/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/skill/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep 10s
cd /skill
npm install
nodemon
```

Comment: Do you have docker configured to use Linux-based containers on windows?

Comment: Just by reading your truncated error message `: not foundypoint.sh: 2: /skill/entrypoint.sh: sleep: invalid time interval '10s\r'` it is almost sure that you have an encoding issue with your script (with Windows newlines "\r\n" instead of Linux newlines "\n")

Comment: @ErikMD  how can I fix it? that it works under windows and linux?

Comment: You could try to follow the suggestions from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885410/9164010), and also make sure that your Git configuration on Windows doesn't silently turn all regular Linux newlines into Windows newlines...