# Using bash to concatenate find/replace command with echo

Tags: regex, bash, shell, perl, replace

I have a CSV file with multiple before/after values which I am using to find and replace values in another large data file (~200MB).

I initially used a loop reading in each before/after value and sed to implement the find and replace.

The issue is that it's understandably a bit slow, so I wanted to try running all of the find/replace in a single line separated by semi-colons to see if it might be faster by only having to traverse the target data file one time.

So I have two values:

```
find="ABC"
replace="DEF"
```

Then I initialized the variable:

```
cmd=""
```

and within the loop, I tried to use this command:

```
cmd="${cmd}s/${find}/${replace}/g;"
```

The idea is to have everything concatenate into one long string like so:

```
"s/FIND1/REP1/g;s/FIND2/REP2/g;s/FIND3/REP3/g; ..." And so on
```

Then I could run the command:

```
perl -i -p -e ${cmd} TARGET_FILE
```

The issue is that my output for the cmd is looking really strange:

```
echo ${cmd}
/DEF/g;ABC
```

The order is totally messed up, I even tried to set ${cmd} to a string like "test" to see what was going on, and the output doesn't change. Somehow the variable order is getting reversed, and the leading "s" is not showing up.

I tried to use printf instead and got the same results. I tried removing the semicolon, changing the forward-slash, escaping the characters, and various other things but nothing seems to be working. Could someone tell me what is going on with this command and why the strange behavior?

Comment: You poorly articulated your problem. Where is a sample of CVS file with `find,replace` pairs? Where is a snippet of `data` file with at least a few lines of data. Are you trying to implement perl `one liner` wrapped into shell script? Or if you want to implement as perl script it would be nice to see your effort in doing so: the code you have tried alredy.

Comment: For a test you could use `perl -0777 -pe 's/$find/$replace/g' file_name` and if you satisfied with result do in place replacement `perl -0777 -e 's/$find/$replace/g' -i.bak file_name`.

Comment: Wrapping perl script into shell's loop is not very efficient -- you ask perl to open script file, read it, analyze it, run it, script exits and now cycle repeats in the loop again and again.

Comment: It looks like your variable has carriage return characters in it, probably because the script and/or CSV file are in DOS/Windows format (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885409/why-would-a-correct-shell-script-give-a-wrapped-truncated-corrupted-error-messag) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)). Convert the files to unix format to avoid trouble.

Comment: Also, double-quote variable references (e.g. `perl -i -p -e "${cmd}" TARGET_FILE` instead of `perl -i -p -e ${cmd} TARGET_FILE`) to avoid the things the shell does to unquoted variable references. I recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) for spotting common mistakes like this.

Comment: @GordonDavisson You were right, the file I received had been created in windows, and I did not know that the ^M caused that type of behavior. I removed the ^M characters and now everything is working fine. Your answer was correct. Considering how much time I spent on this, I will never forget to double check carriage returns. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in a single string is not scalable. Multiple replacements are also not efficient.

This Perl one-liner reads the csv file with patterns and replacements ("before" and "after" values) into the hash `%to`. It then constructs the regex `$pat` by concatenating all the "before" values. Then it reads the file where it replaces "before" with "after" values and prints the result into the output file.

```
cat > pats.csv <<EOF
FIND1,REP1
FIND2,REP2
FIND3,REP3
EOF

cat > in.txt <<EOF
foo FIND1,FIND2,FIND1
bar FIND2 bar
FIND3
EOF

perl -lpe '
BEGIN {
    %to = map { chomp; split m{,}, $_ }
        do { local @ARGV = q{pats.csv}; <> };
    $pat = join q{|}, keys %to;
    $pat = qr{($pat)};
}
s{$pat}{$to{$1}}gxms;
' in.txt > out.txt

cat out.txt
# Prints this:
foo REP1,REP2,REP1
bar REP2 bar
REP3
```